# PHP ldap_bind error

Tags: php, windows, ldap, xampp

I am using xampp on windows 7.
I uncomment the `;extension=php_ldap.dll` to `extension=php_ldap.dll` in php.ini.
then i copy the libeay32.dll, libsasl.dll, ssleay32.dll from C:\xampp\php to C:\Windows\system. and restart apache.

I think all is done well, here is the result in phpInfo function

> LDAP Support - enabled
>
> RCS Version - $Id: 4db15e5bb92af06390fd31ab784837ab21a3d2ce $
>
> Total Links - 0/unlimited
>
> API Version - 3001
>
> Vendor Name - OpenLDAP
>
> Vendor Version - 20433
>
> SASL Support - Enabled

Here is my code

```
<?php
//using ldap bind anonymously
//connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {
    // binding anonymously
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn);

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous failed...";
    }
}
?>
```

I took the code here [php.net/manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php)
And the error massage is

> ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in

Comment: do i need to install OpenLDAP or is it include in xampp package?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with connecting to your LDAP-Server from your webserver. Contrary to the naming `ldap_connect` does **not** connect to the server but verifies that the given server name looks OK (validates as FQDN without doing an actual lookup). The connection is actually done on calling `ldap_bind`. Therefore the connection issue first surfaces on the ldap_bind.

Try to bind to your LDAP-Server from the machine the webserver is running on with a different LDAP-Tool like f.i.. jXplorer. If that doesn't work, there seems to be a network-issue hindering the LDAP-connection.

Just to verify: You *do* have an LDAP-Server running and are not actually trying to literally bind to `ldap.example.com`?